# How to convert the results of `importdata` to simpler struct

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I imported data from a text file w/ a header line, so I have a struct like this:

```
 whos('azdat')
  Name       Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  azdat      1x1             11504  struct  
azdat = 
          data: [61x15 double]
      textdata: {1x15 cell}
    colheaders: {1x15 cell}
```

I'm missing something obvious (I hope) -- how can I  convert this into a struct whose fields are the text strings in `azdat.colheaders` so that I can call columns of data in the new struct with the `newstruct.name` method (where 'name' was one of the strings in `azdat.colheaders` ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this quickly without looping.  The biggest thing is to make sure you're referencing field names dynamically. This is generally done by placing parentheses around the field name.

This [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) on generating field names from variables is probably what you're looking for.

I suspect something similar to the following will work for you.

```
for i = 1:numel(azdat.colheaders)
    newstruct.(azdat.colheaders{i}) = azdat.data(:,i);
end
```

Comment: I think you are missing 2 references to the structure  `azdat` in your loop. i.e. you would need to change the line to this one: `newstruct.(azdat.colheaders{i}) = azdat.data(:,i);` .

Comment: Right you are.  Thanks.

Comment: This is certainly simpler to follow than Luis M's answer!  I suspect both answers take incidental amounts of time to execute.

Comment: Nice use of dynamic field names!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result = cell2struct(mat2cell(data, size(data,1), ones(size(data,2),1)), colheaders, 2);
```

*How it works*: First convert the matrix into a cell array of its columns (`mat2cell(...)`) ; and then convert each cell (that is, each original column) into a field of a struct (`cell2struct(...)`)

For example:

```
>> data = magic(3)
data =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
>> colheaders = {'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'}
colheaders = 
    'aaa'    'bbb'    'ccc'
>> result = cell2struct(mat2cell(data, size(data,1), ones(size(data,2),1)), colheaders, 2)
result = 
    aaa: [3x1 double]
    bbb: [3x1 double]
    ccc: [3x1 double]
>> result.aaa
ans =
     8
     3
     4
```

Comment: This does avoid the need for a loop (as in Ryan's answer). Just wondering if, for  very large datasets, the  creation of the temporary `ones` and `mat2cell` variable will pig out memory?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, that could be so. In that case a `for` loop might be better, as it will use less memory